# Extjs - Call grid url only on tab click

Tags: javascript, extjs

We have an app where grid is loaded dynamically with multiple tabs having one or more grid.The problem is when the application loads itself it is calling all the urls instead i want to call them on tab click to save performance. Grids items are mentioned in Initcomponent method and there is common code for loading different grids.
Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try deferredRender: true config?

Answer (score 1):

Set [autoLoad](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-autoLoad) to false on the underlying stores. Then in a handler for the tab's [click event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.tab.Tab.html#event-click), like you said, call the store's [load](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) method.